# What Stack Exchange site is best for OS X terminal questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about using cURL in OS X terminal, and I'm not sure where would be the best place to ask.

Would it be Super User, or a Linux SE site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kinda depends what you're trying to do?

If you're using cURL in a programming context, Stack Overflow might be the right fit; [it's got over 32k questions on the topic already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl).

For more general questions, I think your guess of Unix & Linux SE is probably best. (Unnecessary technical detail: MacOS/OSX are not Linuxes, but recent versions are POSIX-compliant.) They're a much smaller site, with [fewer than 600 cURL questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curl), but their area of expertise is spot on for command line tools. Super User could be a good second choice if you can't get an answer there.

Also, for completeness, there's Ask Different, an SE site devoted to Apple devices. There are some terminal-related questions there, but overall it's a bit more general interest than you probably want.

Comment: Related: [Is Mac OS X UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/is-mac-os-x-unix)

Comment: Haha that question Alexander linked is, in fact, where I first learned about MacOS's POSIX compliance. There are a bunch of similar posts across the network: U&L [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423121/), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236114/), and [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423121/); SU [1](https://superuser.com/q/223477/), [2](https://superuser.com/q/49434/), [3](https://superuser.com/q/179368/), and [4](https://superuser.com/q/489733/); SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14306771/) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26700003/)